# Not access to while loop in

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new in Python. In this try I think can not access elements in while loop!? How to reach all element in list, first, second, third,.... Please some help.
Here my code:

```
    my_list=[5,8,9,10,22]
    l=len(my_list)
    # only for test output
    print("My list has "+str(l)+" elements.")
    while my_list[l-1]<1:
        print (my_list[l-1])
        if my_list[l-1]<1:
             print(my_list[l-1])
        l+=1         `
```

Comment: You are starting from l = len(my_list) and then are incrementing l inside the loop as well.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

in your code, you are saying

```
while my_list[l-1] < 1:
```

but my_list[l-1] is equal to 10.
10 > 1 so it will never enter your loop.
If you want to print all the elements, you should use a for loop.
If you really want to use a while loop, what you can do is:

```
my_list = [5,8,9,10,22]
my_list_len = len(my_list)
i = 0
while i < my_list_len:
    print(mylist[i])
    i+=1
```

this is an example, and there is many other ways to do that.

Comment: In this case, i `i< my_list_len` at the beginning. It will enter the loop and print the my_list[i]. I will then increase and do the same, until i becomes greater than l. it will exit the loop